# Problemas con dos middlewares y abort 401

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel

estoy usando dos middlewares

FICHERO DE RUTAS

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['web','auth']], function() {

    Route::group(['middleware'=>'administrador'], function() {
       Route::resource('usuarios', 'UsuariosController');
    });

    Route::resource('categorias', 'CategoriasController');
    Route::resource('tags', 'tagsController');
    Route::resource('articulos', 'articulosController');
});

route::any('imagenes','ImagenesController@index');

route::any('front','FrontController@index');
route::any('buscaCat/{nombrecat}','FrontController@buscaCategoria');
route::any('buscaTag/{nombre}','FrontController@buscaTag');
```

el primero es el tipico auth, que es para controlar los que no te muestre las paginas si no estas logueado, y el middleware administrador, es simplemente para que no tengas acceso a ciertas rutas, pero llevo un rato probando y no consigo hacer funcionar los dos a la vez.

Middleware auth (por defecto)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

    class Authenticate
    {
        /**
         * Handle an incoming request.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  \Closure  $next
         * @param  string|null  $guard
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
        {
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
                if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
                    return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
                } else {
                    return redirect()->guest('login');
                }
            }

            return $next($request);
        }
    }
```

MIDDLEWARE ADMINISTRADOR

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Closure;

class administrador
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {


       if(!is_null(Auth::user()) and Auth::user()->tipo!= 'administrador'):
        abort(401);
       else:
                return $next($request);
       endif;

    }
}
```

VISTA ERROR 401 PERSONALIZADO

```
   <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="title">PERMISO DENEGADO, NO PUEDES ENTRAR AQUI</div>
                <div >
                    <a href="{{url('front')}}" class="btn btn-primary">Volver</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

KERNEL MIDDLEWARE

```
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,

            //*****************PERSONALIZADO***************************************
           \App\Http\Middleware\administrador::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
          //*****************PERSONALIZADO***************************************
         'administrador' => \App\Http\Middleware\administrador::class,

    ];
}
```

El middleware administrador lo he probado en el ficherod de rutas y en el controlador usuarios, y el resultado es el mismo.

El problema cuando aplica el abort es que me lo aplica A TODAS, absolutamente todas las rutas, incluso las no definidas en los grupos de  rutas del middleware, por poner un ejemplo, cuando entro siendo otra cosa que no sea administrador me salta la pantalla, pero luego ya no puedo volver hacia atras ni con las flechas del navegador y si pruebo a cambiar la ruta desde la barra de direcciones, el mensaje permanece, solo puedo acceder a la pagina comentando los grupos de rutas y comentando el middleware en el kernel.

Si intento acceder a  una ruta como front, que no tendria que tener problemas en acceder, el mensaje permanece. Luego si intento hacer una redireccion en vez del abort, pienso que entra en conflicto con el primer middleware y hace una redireccion infinita.

¿Que opciones tengo?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás aplicando el middleware 'administrador' al grupo (de middlewares) web:

```
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,

        //*****************PERSONALIZADO***************************************
       \App\Http\Middleware\administrador::class,
    ],
```

Este grupo de middlewares se aplica a TODAS las rutas, a menos que lo hayas modificado en el service provider correspondiente.

En el código actual de Laravel, el [RouteServiceProvider](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L53) lo muestra:

```
/**
 * Define the routes for the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
 * @return void
 */
public function map(Router $router)
{
    $this->mapWebRoutes($router);
    //
}

/**
 * Define the "web" routes for the application.
 *
 * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
 * @return void
 */
protected function mapWebRoutes(Router $router)
{
    $router->group([
        'namespace' => $this->namespace, 'middleware' => 'web',
    ], function ($router) {
        require app_path('Http/routes.php');
    });
}
```

¿Qué opciones tienes?

- Modificar el route service provider para que no incluya por defecto el middleware 'web' en todas las rutas.
- Dejar el middleware administrador fuera del grupo 'web' y aplicarlo solo a las rutas específicas.

La mejor opción depende del diseño de tu aplicación.

Comment: Como siempre una respuesta excelente, FUNCIONO perfectamente. Gracias